# Rails 4 generate add underscore to my model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the code and the stupid underscore.
I am using rails 4

```
rails generate scaffold USER ip:string{20} nickname:string{100} visitnum:integer
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20141015211014_create_users.rb
  create    app/models/user.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/user_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/users.yml
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :users
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/use_rs_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/use_rs
  create      app/views/use_rs/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/use_rs/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/use_rs/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/use_rs/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/use_rs/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/controllers/use_rs_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/use_rs_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/helpers/use_rs_helper_test.rb
  invoke    jbuilder
  create      app/views/use_rs/index.json.jbuilder
  create      app/views/use_rs/show.json.jbuilder
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/use_rs.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/use_rs.css.scss
  invoke  scss
  identical    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
```

Why the users become use_rs ? This looks stupid and very troublesome to my work

Comment: Why are you naming your model in all uppercase letters? Though I can't explain why exactly rails is doing this, it is not expecting to take an uppercase name. It should be named "User" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because to generate the names Rails first calls `pluralize` on `"USER"` resulting in `"USERs"` (note the case), and then calls `underscore` when generating various names. `"USERs".underscore = "use_rs"`. Run the following command instead (with `user` in lowercase):

```
rails generate scaffold user ip:string{20} nickname:string{100} visitnum:integer
```